# How to reproduce a sound sequence using <audio> tag html5

Tags: javascript, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, audio

Actually im new in Ruby on Rails 4 programming with HTML5 ,so here's the question:

How can I reproduce a defined sequence of sounds on a Rails 4 application?
I mean, I need to listen to different sounds reproduced one by one, and between each sound should be a time interval.

Example:

```
START  
< sound 1 >
1 sec of silence 
< sound 2 >  
1 sec of silence 
< sound n >  
END
```

Also I need that the sounds sequence must stat byitself/autoplay.
Help!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A javascript function that takes a list of **[audio](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)** elements and plays them with a pause of 1 second between them.

Included at the end of the html document.

```js
(function() {
  var track1 = document.getElementById('track1');
  var track2 = document.getElementById('track2');
  var track3 = document.getElementById('track3');

  var trackList = [];

  trackList.push(track1);
  trackList.push(track2);
  trackList.push(track3);

  playTracks(trackList); // call the function so it starts playing the 1st song

  ///
  // plays a list of audio elements
  function playTracks(tracks) {
    var curentSong = tracks.shift(); // take out the 1st song in order to play it
    curentSong.play(); // play it
    curentSong.onended = function() { // when it ends
      setTimeout(function() { // wait 1 second
        playTracks(tracks); // play the rest of the list
      }, 1000);
    };
  }
})(); // IIFE so it starts as soon as it's loaded
```

Another option to start it would be on the [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event.

```js
function startMusic() {
  var track1 = document.getElementById('track1');
  var track2 = document.getElementById('track2');
  var track3 = document.getElementById('track3');

  var trackList = [];

  trackList.push(track1);
  trackList.push(track2);
  trackList.push(track3);

  playTracks(trackList); // call the function so it starts playing the 1st song

  ///
  // plays a list of audio elements
  function playTracks(tracks) {
    var curentSong = tracks.shift(); // take out the 1st song in order to play it
    curentSong.play(); // play it
    curentSong.onended = function() { // when it ends
      setTimeout(function() { // wait 1 second
        playTracks(tracks); // play the rest of the list
      }, 1000);
    };
  }
}

// start playing after the page loads
window.onload = startMusic;
```

The audio elements can be generated by the server.

```
<audio>
    <source src="<%= $pathOfTheSound %>"></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: can i put a rails tag <%= $pathOfTheSound %> into this js function?

Comment: no, you will have to embed that in the audio element in the page. what you can do is create a javascript variable containing the ids of the audio elements.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance ,but what does it mean IIFE? TY :D

Comment: an Imediately Invoked Function Expression, you can check this post for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: Actually the script is not working, i mean that the browser is giving me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannor read property 'play' of null. The script code is the same you gave me and every single <audio> has this code: <audio preload ><source src="sound1.wav" id="track1"></source>sound1</audio>

Comment: That code should be loaded after the page is done loading. Either import the file containing it at the end (right before body is closed), or move it to the onload event. I will make an example with the onload solution. :)